# How I reference hash inside of subroutine?

Tags: perl

I am trying to use the tie function of the module [Config::IniFiles](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Config-IniFiles-2.65/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm) but I cannot figure out how to reference the hash inside of sub routine. If I remove the tie function and related code from the sub routine it works perfectly.

This is the line I thought would work, but tells me that "$cfg" is not initialized.

```
use Config::IniFiles
sub config_file {
    my $cfg_file = 'settings.ini';
    my %cfg;
    tie %cfg, 'Config::IniFiles', ( -file => "$cfg_file" );

    #my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => $cfg_file );

}

sub esx_host_check {
    my $esx_host = config_file()->$cfg{ESX}{host};
}
```

I am sure it is something simple, but I am stumped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, the `tie` function returns the internal hidden object that represents the tie, and not the tied variable itself.  Secondly, you can not return a plural tied value (hash or array) from a subroutine and have it work the way you are expecting.  You need to return a reference to the plural value, and then dereference it when you need to use it.

```
use Config::IniFiles;

sub config_file {
    tie my %cfg, 'Config::IniFiles', -file => 'settings.ini';  # tie variable
    return \%cfg;  # return a reference to the tied variable
}

sub esx_host_check {
    my $esx_host = config_file()->{ESX}{host}; # call sub and dereference value
}
```

If you are going to use the config hash more than a few times, its probably best to build it and then cache the result:

```
{my $cfg;
sub config_file {
    tie %$cfg, 'Config::IniFiles', -file => 'settings.ini' unless $cfg;
    return $cfg;
}}
```

This is a little different than above.  First, we setup `config_file` to be a closure around the private variable `$cfg`.  Note that it is a scalar and not a hash.  Then in the sub, we check to see if the variable has been initialized, and if not, call `tie`.  `tie` is passed a first argument of `%$cfg` which dereferences the undefined value as a hash, which has the effect of storing the tied hash reference into `$cfg`.

While a little more complicated, this technique will only need to build the config hash once, potentially saving a lot of time.

Comment: Ok it works, but let me see if I understand because it means nothing if I just copy and paste the code. So sub config_file return a reference to the hash, so when I call the subroutine to give a value to $esx_host I only need to tell it what I am looking for since the subroutine is already referencing the hash. Right?

Comment: @Solignis => correct, the constructor sub `config_file()` is returning the hash reference, so in `esx_host_check` you just need to dereference the value returned by the sub, you do not need to name it.

Comment: So as for the part about caching the hash. Let me see if I understand, I am storing the value of "sub config_file" in side of a scalar?.

Answer (score 1):

(1) always start your perl code with `use strict`. You should have received a warning in `esx_host_check()` about an unknown `%cfg`

(2) use `use vars(...)` to implement "global" identifiers:

```
use vars qw(%cfg);

sub one
    {
        tie %cfg, ....
    }

sub two
    {
        my $value = $cfg{foo}{bar};
    }
```

Comment: I just did not add it to the question, I start all of my scripts with #!/usr/bin/perl
,use strict;
,use warnings;

Comment: So you actually *got* the error about an unreferenced `%cfg`?

Comment: yeah, let me see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: `use vars` is deprecated; `our %var` is better.

Comment: @Ether +1 I know. My original answer actually mentioned `our` before `use vars`. Just to point out the use of global variables I sheepishly decided to use the "outdated" way...

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring %cfg with my (good!), so it's only visible inside the config_file sub; You then tie it, which returns the underlying Config::IniFiles object, and, as it is the last entry of the function, it returns that object... So I'm not sure why you are tie'ing in the first place, rather than just using the commented line.

In any case, config_file() returns a Config::IniFiles object. You then try to call a method, named by the contents of the variable $cfg{ESX}{host}.. A variable that doesn't exist!

If you want to use the tie interface, add a return \%cfg; to the end of config_file. If you want to use the object interface.. Well, I can only point you to the docs.

Comment: I see so I need to return the hash not the tie object, right?

Comment: That'd fix part of the problem, yeah. I'd take a look at Eric Strom's post for the rest.