# How do I use "tied" against a subroutine?

Tags: perl

I seem to have a small issue with my script where I need to call "tied" against a sub routine that is earlier in the the script so that I can access the functions that are related to the object that the hash is tied to. The problem is when I go to run the script it return the error "Can't call method "SetWriteMode" on unblessed reference at cbc_encrypt_test.pl line 30." At first I had no idea what it was talking about, I think the problem is due to me using a reference to point back at the subroutine which return the hash reference in the first place. Because as far I understand "config_file = \%cfg" in this case. After looking at perldoc about perlref's I am still lost. I read over the document pretty well and did not see anything about referencing subroutines in the way I need to.

Here the entire script so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use warnings;

use Term::ANSIColor;

use Config::IniFiles;

use Crypt::CBC;

start_script();



sub start_script {

    system ("clear");

    encrypt_password();

} # end start_script

sub config_file {

    my $cfg_file = 'settings.ini';

    my %cfg;

    tie %cfg, 'Config::IniFiles', ( -file => "$cfg_file" );

    return \%cfg;

} # end config_file

sub encrypt_password {
    my $password = config_file()->{ESX}{password};
    my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new( -key => 'EF1FAD9B87F8365B242669E624FEB36CDBCCFEE0096CC45DDDCF6F5995E83F61',
                    -cipher => 'Rijndael'
                    );
    my $encrypted_password = $cipher->encrypt_hex("$password");
    chomp $encrypted_password;
    config_file()->{ESX}{password} = $encrypted_password;
    tied config_file()->SetWriteMode(0666);
    tied config_file()->RewriteConfig();
    return $encrypted_password;
} # end encrypt_password
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a precedence issue. Running the construct through `B::Deparse` shows the problem:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e 'tied config_file()->method()'
tied(config_file()->method);
-e syntax OK
```

So Perl first tries to call the method on the reference returned by `config_file()`, and fails because that reference is not a blessed object (like `tied` would return).

Instead try:

```
tied(%{config_file()})->SetWriteMode(0666);
tied(%{config_file()})->RewriteConfig();
```

or better yet:

```
my $cfg = tied %{config_file()};
$cfg->SetWriteMode(0666);
$cfg->RewriteConfig();
```

or

```
for (tied %{config_file()}) {
    $_->SetWriteMode(0666);
    $_->RewriteConfig();
}
```

Also, depending on how `Config::IniFiles` is written, you may run into problems where each call to `config_file()` returns a new object, so the aggregate calls you make don't apply to each other properly.  You should cache the object as shown in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493517/how-i-reference-hash-inside-of-subroutine/4493815#4493815).

Edit:  I didn't catch the missing dereference that ysth pointed out which would have been the second problem.  Fixed above.

Comment: What is B::Deparse? a CPAN module?

Comment: `B::Deparse` is a core module that you already have installed.  In the usage above, Perl takes the `-e` line, compiles it, and then passes the compiled op-tree to `B::Deparse` which converts the op-tree back to Perl source code.  The `-p` option tells deparse to insert parenthesis where they implicitly are.

Comment: I must have missed the part about caching in my other question. The above solution(s) work but now I am finding out that the config module is not actually writing a password so I got more fun ahead of me.

Answer (score 4):

tied needs to be used on a tied variable.  If you have a reference to such a variable, you can do this:

```
tied( %{ config_file() } )
```

but in your code as it stands, each call to config_file will create a new tied hash, and methods you had called on the previous hash's tied object will have done no good, so you need to ensure that config_file() is only called once (or have it internally memoize its result).

Comment: +1, I focused on the precedence issue and looked right past the missing dereference